# UpdatePanel is not a known element in VSStudio 2010 Design View

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, updatepanel

[image]

I am using UpdatePanel in the ASPX page and I could not get rid of this message however I tried.  I could run the page without errors and update panel is working fine.  But, I could not solve that error in the VSStudio Design View.

I do have web.config file in my website.

Could you please help me to solve that?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:UpdatePanel>` needs to have a `<Triggers>` element before the `<ContentTemplate>`.  Not having that present probably puts you in the "compilation error in the web site" section of that error message.

Answer (score 0):

First make a backup of web.config file...

Then try removing Reference for System.Web.Extentions and add it again (remember versions of the files before removing and after adding again) then check the web.config and 
replace the old version no with new version no for the entries of System.Web.Extentions.